# C Codes servers and External network

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

Not long ago I made a client and server codes Using the C language and the libraries of Winsock and Ws2tcpip

My Client and server can only communicate with each other if they are in the same network

But I want to learn and change the codes So they could communicate in long distance without needing to use Programs like Hamachi or Evolve (Port forward if I'm not mistaken)

So if anyone knows how do I do that Please write that down below
If the code samples are needed tell me and I will add them right up :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to use port forwarding on your router.

Comment: this question seems to be requesting opinions.  It also seems to be requesting help with a network problem.  That is offtopic.  either of these characteristics will get the question closed very quickly, without an answer.  Suggest posting the code so we can debug it.

Comment: I asked if you want me to post the codes.

Comment: @Qwerty01 I want to avoid using Port forward

Comment: There isn't any way to do it without port forwarding.  Hamachi uses a main server to forward the connection, which does the port forwarding; P2P will use things like uPnP, and Skype has used hole punching, all of which require port forwarding at some level.  The whole purpose of a firewall is to prevent what you're trying to do, which is why port forwarding is required at some point.

Comment: To extend what @Qwerty01 said, there is only one way to have client-to-client communication when there are firewalls in the middle and do not wish to use any port forwarding; you must use a central server that the individual clients can connect to.

Comment: So how do I do this without Hamachi? Or any kind of that software? Do I just try to enable a port in my computer through my firewall?